# How to get the current CPU/RAM/Disk usage in a C# web application using .NET CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am currently looking for a way to get the current CPU/RAM/Disk usage in a C# web application using .NET CORE.

For CPU and ram usage, I use PerformanceCounter Class from `System.Diagnostics`.

These are the codes:

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
PerformanceCounter ramCounter;

cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

public string getCurrentCpuUsage(){
    cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%";
}

public string getAvailableRAM(){
    ramCounter.NextValue()+"MB";
}
```

For disk usage, I am using the `DriveInfo` class. These are the codes:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Info {
    public static void Main() {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives) {
            //There are more attributes you can use.
            //Check the MSDN link for a complete example.
            Console.WriteLine(drive.Name);
            if (drive.IsReady) Console.WriteLine(drive.TotalSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately .NET Core does not support the `DriveInfo` and `PerformanceCounter` classes, hence the codes above do not work.

Does anyone know how I can get the current CPU/RAM/Disk usage in a C# web application using .NET CORE?

Comment: See this open issue: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9376

Comment: Is P/Invoke in .NET core? I'm not 100% ramped up on coreclr, yet, but if you have P/Invoke and can call native Windows libs, there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `PerformnceCounter` in the `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter/)

for example, the next code will give you the total processor usage percent

```
var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total",true);
var value = cpuCounter.NextValue();
//Note: In most cases you need to call .NextValue() twice to be able to get the real value
if (Math.Abs(value) <= 0.00)
    value = cpuCounter.NextValue();

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

you can do the same for all OS registered Performance Counters.

---

### **Update:**

I'm not sure if there is something I should do after creating a new instance of the PerformanceCounter class, but sometimes when I get the next value it comes as 0.

**So I've decided to make one instance of PerformanceCounter in at the application level.**

e.g.

```
public static class DiagnosticHelpers
{
    static float _systemCPU;
    public static float SystemCPU 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            lock (locker)
            {
                return _systemCPU;
            }
        }
    }

    private static readonly object locker = new object();


    static DiagnosticHelpers()
    {
        SystemCPU = 0;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", true);
            cpuCounter.NextValue(); //prime the counter
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); /wait at least 1 second before the first real read
                lock (locker)
                {
                    _systemCPU = cpuCounter.NextValue();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue?view=netcore-3.1#remarks the recommended delay is indeed one second.

Comment: "the first read operation using the new properties returns 0.0." You have to read it at least once to prime the counter.

Comment: Locking for writes to `SystemCPU` don't help unless reads are locked as well.

Answer (score 4):

Processor information is available via `System.Diagnostics`:

```
var proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var mem = proc.WorkingSet64;
var cpu = proc.TotalProcessorTime;
Console.WriteLine("My process used working set {0:n3} K of working set and CPU {1:n} msec", 
    mem / 1024.0, cpu.TotalMilliseconds);
```

`DriveInfo` is available for Core by adding the `System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo` package

Comment: How to get the CPU percentage?

Comment: Note also that this is the process-specific CPU usage, not the system CPU usage, which is what OP's performance counter tracks.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows i'm using this

```
var memorieLines= GetWmicOutput("OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize /Value").Split("\n");

var freeMemory= memorielines[0].Split("=", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
var totalMemory = memorielines[1].Split("=", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];

var cpuLines = GetWmicOutput("CPU get Name,LoadPercentage /Value").Split("\n");

var CpuUse = cpuLines[0].Split("=", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
var CpuName = cpuLines[1].Split("=", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];


private string GetWmicOutput(string query, bool redirectStandardOutput = true)
{
   var info = new ProcessStartInfo("wmic");

   info.Arguments = query;
   info.RedirectStandardOutput = redirectStandardOutput;

   var output = string.Empty;

   using (var process = Process.Start(info))
   {
      output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   }

   return output.Trim();
}
```

For the disk infos you can use this query :

```
LOGICALDISK get Caption,DeviceID,FileSystem,FreeSpace,Size /Value
```

if you want a better output formatting give a look to this article : https://www.petri.com/command-line-wmi-part-3

Comment: Works in 2022 for a NET Core 6 console app.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Add this nuget package to your project by double clicking project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" Version="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When you run the code, you will get an error like below.

```
Performance counters cannot be initialized! System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
```

To solve this error, you have to add your application pool user to "Performance Monitor Users" group.
Open command line in administrator mode, then run this command.

```
net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" "IIS APPPOOL\MYAPPPOOL"  /add
```

MYAPPPOOL will be replaced with your real app pool name.

Then restart the machine if iis restart does not solve.