# Asp.Net Core Get Server Hardware Usage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm created an asp.net core web api application.
I want to get current server cpu/ram usage as percent.
This application is will not scale never and this anytime will running on the one Windows server.
How can i get the server cpu/ram usage as percent?

Comment: Those are about the most useless metrics you can get. You want response times, time waiting on code, disk, network or database, and so on. Anyway see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675734/cpu-usage-in-net-core-at-least-on-windows, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523669/how-to-get-the-current-cpu-ram-disk-usage-in-a-c-sharp-web-application-using-ne