# How to get CPU Usage and Virtual Memory for a process in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

In .NET Core, how to get the CPU usage and Virtual Memory for a given process?

Google search result reveals that PerformanceCounter and DriverInfo class could do the job. However, PerformanceCounter & DriverInfo class are not available in .NET Core.

There is a post in stackoverflow about this question: [How to get the current CPU/RAM/Disk usage in a C# web application using .NET CORE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523669/how-to-get-the-current-cpu-ram-disk-usage-in-a-c-sharp-web-application-using-ne)

However it only addresses:
-CPU usage for the current process:

```
    var proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

I have been given process (with a ProcessID integer format). How do I get the CPU Usage and Virtual Memory for that particular process in .NET Core?

Comment: Sounds like .Net Core is currently the wrong choice for your requirements. Why not just use the .Net Framework?

Comment: The code I wrote above is for .Net core. Not .Net Framework

Comment: I know... My point being, why are you using .Net Core? Is there a specific reason why you are using it over .Net Framework?

Comment: @JamieRees, that function above needs to work in .Net Core because the project needs to run in web apps and services for Windows, Linux, macOS, and Docker.

Comment: That still can be done in .Net Framework with Mono

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PerformnceCounter` in the `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter/)

for example, the next code will give you the total processor usage percent

```
var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", true);
var value = cpuCounter.NextValue();
// In most cases you need to call .NextValue() twice
if (Math.Abs(value) <= 0.00)
    value = cpuCounter.NextValue();

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: PerformnceCounter is not supported for Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to get **netcore process memory**:

```
var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var workingSet64 = process.WorkingSet64;
var privateMemorySize64 = process.PrivateMemorySize64;
var virtualMemorySize64 = process.VirtualMemorySize64;
```

And for **CPU usage**:

```
    private static DateTime? _previousCpuStartTime = null;
    private static TimeSpan? _previousTotalProcessorTime = null;

    private static double GetCpuUsageForProcess()
    {
        var currentCpuStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var currentCpuUsage = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;

        // If no start time set then set to now
        if (!_previousCpuStartTime.HasValue)
        {
            _previousCpuStartTime = currentCpuStartTime;
            _previousTotalProcessorTime = currentCpuUsage;
        }

        var cpuUsedMs = (currentCpuUsage - _previousTotalProcessorTime.Value).TotalMilliseconds;
        var totalMsPassed = (currentCpuStartTime - _previousCpuStartTime.Value).TotalMilliseconds;
        var cpuUsageTotal = cpuUsedMs / (Environment.ProcessorCount * totalMsPassed);

        // Set previous times.
        _previousCpuStartTime = currentCpuStartTime;
        _previousTotalProcessorTime = currentCpuUsage;

        return cpuUsageTotal * 100.0;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

I just typed in 'get all processes in c#' into google and found this:

```
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
        {
        }
```

i quickly tested in asp.net core 2.2 and it works fine using System.Diagnostics;
However i used windows 10 pro to test it. So i dont know if it will work with other operating systems.

Source: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/get-a-list-of-running-processes-in-c/

Comment: GetProcesses() is listed as applying to dotnetcore in [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=netcore-2.2#applies-to).