# How to measure CPU usage and memory for a process in .Net Core (linux)

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

PerformanceCounter class has been commonly used to profile a process by getting CPU usage and memory.

However, PerformanceCounter does not work in Linux. I could not change my project from .NET Core to .NET standard or .NET framework

I have checked this post: [How to get CPU Usage and Virtual Memory for a process in .Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178660/how-to-get-cpu-usage-and-virtual-memory-for-a-process-in-net-core).

However I could not use Mono in my work.

Some website (https://stackify.com/performance-counters-net-core/) reveals that EventCounter in .NET Core could do the job but another forum https://gitter.im/dotnet/coreclr/archives/2017/02/08 has confirmed that it does not work.

How do I measure CPU usage and memory in .NET Core without using PerformanceCounter?

Comment: `.NET Standard` is only for class libraries. It can't access Windows OS features like performance counters that aren't available on Linux. The links you provide are in reverse order too. EventCounter was  probably not working in February 2017 when the forum post was made. Stackify's article was posted on November 2017 and says EventCounters *may* appear in 2.1.

Comment: Check [EventCounter's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventcounter?view=netcore-2.2) documentation. It's available but its job is to *post* measurements, not read them. Performance Counters are used for that reason in most Windows applications too. It's another tool's job to collect a trace of performance counters, eg Performance Monitor

Comment: [This article](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/linux-performance-tracing.md?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) shows how to do performance tracing on Linux. Check [Introduction Tutorial: How to measure performance for very frequent events using EventCounters](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.Tracing/documentation/EventCounterTutorial.md) too. Normal perf reporting is done through EventSource, EventCounters are meant for very frequent events

Comment: For coarse metrics like CPU and memory usage you can use the [/proc](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) folder. If you know the processID you want you can read `/proc/thatID/status` to read memory usage

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you for your comment. Maybe I did not specify clearly in my question. How do I get CPU & memory usage in C# code, which can work in .NET Core linux?

Comment: If you mean checking metrics for the *current* process you can use the properties of the [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64?view=netframework-4.7.2), both on Windows and Linux. Perf counters are mainly used for monitoring other processes though. Publishing metrics and recording them has to go through event sources, event counters and trace collection